# Привязка событий клавиатуры к кнопкам на Angular16

Tags: angular

необходимо сделать HotKey как в desktop приложении, привязать HotKey к кнопкам в компоненте Angular.
Если я привяжу кнопки через события "`keydown.1" "keydown.2"` то вызов события при нажатии на `1` или `2` происходит только когда кнопка в фокусе, т.е. если фокус находится на другом элементе то эти события не срабатывают.
Можно ли подписаться на стрим событий с кнопок и его обрабатывать в фоне?
Например `Obdervable<KeyboardEvent> keys$`;

*app.component.html*

```
<div>
  <button
    class="btn-primary"
    tabindex="0"
    (keydown.1)="keyDown($event)"
  >Button1</button>

  <button
    class="btn-primary"
    tabindex="0"
    (keydown.2)="keyDown($event)"
  >Button2</button>
</div>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
  keyDownEnter($event: any)  {
    console.log($event);
  }
```

Comment: Вам наверное [@HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) нужен. Либо подписывайтесь с помощью [fromEvent](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent).

Comment: Спасибо посмотрю.

Comment: "@HostListener" помог. Прослушиваются все события компонента где он указан. Если  @HostListener в AppComponent то возможно перехватывать нажатия клавиш не зависимо от фокуса на элементе.